# How to concatenate pandas dataframes with override on one column?

Tags: python, pandas, join, overriding, concatenation

Considering the following dataframes:

```
import pandas as pd

data1={'column_a' : ['a','a','b','c','d','e'],
      'column_b' : [1,2,3,4,5,6],
      'column_c' : [9,8,6,4,5,4]}

data2={'column_a' : ['f','f','g','a','a','a'],
      'column_b' : [7,8,9,7,5,6],
      'column_c' : [6,8,7,6,5,4]}

df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

How would you concatenate the 2 dataframes so that `df_2` would append to `df_1`, but override `df_1` on `column_a`?
I am looking for the following result

```
column_a    column_b    column_c
b   3   6
c   4   4
d   5   5
e   6   4
f   7   6
f   8   8
g   9   7
a   7   6
a   5   5
a   6   4
```

Note how the 2 rows at the top with 'a', from `df_1` are no longer availble, as they were overridden by the 3 a's from `df_2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do one filter before `append` or `concat`

```
pd.concat([df_1.loc[~df_1.column_a.isin(df_2.column_a)],df_2])
Out[29]: 
  column_a  column_b  column_c
2        b         3         6
3        c         4         4
4        d         5         5
5        e         6         4
0        f         7         6
1        f         8         8
2        g         9         7
3        a         7         6
4        a         5         5
5        a         6         4
```